# SwiftUI alert view not showing up when TableRow context menu button is clicked

Tags: swiftui, core-data, alert

I try to show an alert view when user is going to delete a selected table-row. The delete button is part of a table-row context menu. I think this is because table-row is not a view but when moving the alert to the table view I cannot access `secretItem` from the ForEach loop anymore. So how to delete rows (object items) from a table with alert views on context menu buttons

Any guidance for me?

```
struct SecretDetailView: View {
  @State private var showDeleteAlert = false

  var table: some View {
    Table(selection: $selection, sortOrder: $sortOrder) {
        TableColumn("User Name", value: \.userName)
        ...
  } rows: {
        ForEach(secretItems) { secretItem in
            TableRow(secretItem)
                // Menue showing up with right click on table row for row manipulation
                .contextMenu {
                    Button("Delete Item") {
                        showDeleteAlert.toggle()
                    }
                    // alert not showing up here:
                    .alert(isPresented: $showDeleteAlert) {
                        Alert(
                            title: Text("Do you want to delete item?"),
                            message: Text(""),
                            primaryButton: .cancel(
                                Text("Cancel"),
                                action: { }
                            ),
                            secondaryButton: .destructive(
                                Text("Delete"),
                                action: {deleteSelectedSecretItem(secretItem) }
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `alert` overloads that takes in a value to be presented, such as [`alert(_:isPresented:presenting:actions:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/alert(_:ispresented:presenting:actions:)-78spw) or [`alert(item:content:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/alert(item:content:)) (deprecated in iOS 17). This way, you can move the `alert` modifier to be on the `Table` instead.

Add a new `@State` to store the item to be deleted, and set this in the context menu "Delete" button's action.

```
// assuming secretItems is an array of "Item"
@State private var toBeDeletedItem: Item?
```

```
.contextMenu {
    Button("Delete Item") {
        showDeleteAlert.toggle()
        toBeDeletedItem = item
    }
}
```

```
// add this to the Table
.alert("Do you want to delete item?", isPresented: $showDeleteAlert, presenting: toBeDeletedItem) { item in
    Button("Delete", role: .destructive) {
        deleteSelectedSecretItem(item)
    }

    Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) { }
}
```

Or if you are on an earlier version and `alert(_:isPresented:presenting:actions:)` is not available:

```
.alert(item: $toBeDeletedItem) { item in
    Alert(
        title: Text("Do you want to delete item?"),
        message: Text(""),
        primaryButton: .cancel(
            Text("Cancel"),
            action: { }
        ),
        secondaryButton: .destructive(
            Text("Delete"),
            action: { deleteSelectedSecretItem(item) }
        )
    )
}
// You don't actually need showDeleteAlert!
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. Your first approach is working great. One question. When moving the alert to the end of the table a message is showing up in the xcode console as soon as the alert view is showing up: `CGSWindowShmemCreateWithPort failed on port 0`. But it works without errors . Any ideas?

Comment: @JFS Seems like something macOS specific - I don't get that on iOS. I found [this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/727803) about the message.